# cakephp download png file

Tags: php, html, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I dynamically generate png files which after clicking "generate" button appears "under"  link.

```
 "generate button : click" ---> <a href="new_generated.png">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

After clicking link DOWNLOAD I wish content of link(in my case png) start download  - no open in another window but download! 
I am using cakePHP. Can I please for help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively if you are using Apache web server and have mod_headers enabled you can use an .htaccess file to force download of the png files.

Create a .htacess file and place it in the directory where your png files are being generated/downloaded from.  In that file put this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:png)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: image = image.replace("image/png", "application/octet-stream");

Answer (score 0):

you can use the MediaView to pass it through and force downloading:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/media-view.html?highlight=media#MediaView

Comment: But as far as understand i must put it in "app/outside_webroot_dir/.."    but generated files is outcome of "canvas.toDataURL("image/png", true);" I have no idea how to place it in this directory....

Comment: well, if it is such a tmp generated file you can use the new 2.0 features of the $response object: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-attachments