# Download canvas image on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, download, qr-code

I have `<div id="qrcode"></div>`

Then  `jquery.qrcode.js plugin creates over a`` element with the QR Code.

So, i would like to put a `<button>` element in the page for downloading that "image" (it's a canvas element) created on the fly.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jquery canvas image download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885761/jquery-canvas-image-download)

> The saving of the image can be done using HTML5 blobs.
>
> http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-file-writing
>
> You can get Blob out of the  like done in this code:
>
> https://github.com/miohtama/Krusovice/blob/master/src/tools/resizer.js

Comment: mmmmmmm ... it looks so good html5 but i would like to use other method if possible.

Comment: Your using Canvas? Canvas IS Html5?

Comment: But your question is about saving from a canvas? How can you remove canvas?